# Погрешность спидометра

Tags: математика

Нужно решить следующую задачу:
Человек нечаянно сломал стрелку на спидометре, после чего вставил свою стрелку в спидометр, но вышло так, что эта стрелка имеет погрешность, и не показывает настоящую скорость авто, то есть имеет погрешность в одну из сторон. Затем человек провел замеры (одна поездка с разной скоростью), и получил следующие результаты:

Первая поедка заняла **5 часов**

1. Проехал первые **4 км** со скоростью **-1 км/час**
2. Дальше ехал **4 км** со скоростью **0 км/час**
3. Дальше ехал **10 км** со скоростью **3 км/час**

Погрешность, которую высчитал водитель в этом случае составила 3.0 км/час **(было дано в условии, я не высчитывал это сам, ибо не знаю как)**

То есть выходит, что первые **4 км** он ехал **2 км/час** , слеудющие **4 км** ехать **3 км/час**, остальные **10 км** ехал **3 км/час**.

Аналогично, ещё пример:
Общее время езды - **10 часов**

1. Проехал первые **5 км** со скоростью **3 км/час**
2. Дальше ехал **2 км** со скоростью **2 км/час**
3. Дальше ехал **3 км** со скоростью **6 км/час**
4. Дальше ехал **3 км** со скоростью **1 км/час**

Погрешность: **-0.508653377**

Хочу понять лишь как решать такое, думал уже очень долгое время, идей нет, по этому пишу сюда. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не относится ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос не по теме сайта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну пусть эта погрешность d. Разберем первую задачу.

Он ехал со скоростью d-1 4км за время 4/(d-1), потом 4 со скоростью в за время 4/d, потом еще 10/(d+3).

Итого 4/(d-1)+4/d+10/(d+3) = 5

Ищем отсюда d, находим, что d == 3.

Comment: А общую формулу для d могли бы написать если не сложно?

Comment: Для каждого уравнения — своя, как вы понимаете... В общем случае — уравнение n-й степени...

Answer (score 2):

Вот смотрите - известно общее время и длины участков. Значит, можно составить уравнение

```
5/(3+x) + 2/(2+x) +.. =10 часов
```

Здесь x - неизвестная поправка